# how to calculate experience using from date to leaving date

Tags: javascript, date, date-arithmetic

I have two type of date month wise how to calculate experience in javascript 
example:july-2013 to march-2013

```
// Assumes Date From (df) and Date To (dt) are valid etc...
var df= new Date("01/15/2010");
var dt = new Date("02/01/2012");   
var allMonths= dt.getMonth() - df.getMonth() + (12 * (dt.getFullYear() -     df.getFullYear()));
var allYears= dt.getFullYear() - df.getFullYear();
var partialMonths = dt.getMonth() - df.getMonth();
if (partialMonths < 0) {
allYears--;
partialMonths = partialMonths + 12;
}
var total = allYears + " years and " + partialMonths + " months between the dates.";
var totalMonths = "A total of " + allMonths + " between the dates.";
console.log(total);
console.log(totalMonths);  


return {jaren: allYears, maanden: partialMonths};
```

Comment: why you tagging Java for JavaScript.?

Comment: Tagged `java`, code `javascript` and question description says `java` again. What is this?!

Comment: Besides, what is the problem with your code?! What is the error you're getting? What's the actual and expected output. Please provide these details as well.

Comment: The distinction can no doubt be confusing to beginners. Edited and re-tagged.

Answer (score 3):

Convert everything to months and subtract them. Then divide it by 12. The division will be the years, and the remainder the months of experience. Something like this:

```
var startMonth = df.getFullYear() * 12 + df.getMonth();  
var endMonth = dt.getFullYear() * 12 + dt.getMonth();
var monthInterval = (endMonth - startMonth);

var yearsOfExperience = Math.floor (monthInterval / 12);
var monthsOfExperience = monthInterval % 12;
```